# Can't connect Sqlalchemy with pyodbc to SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, sql-server-2000

I followed this [website](https://gist.github.com/kriwil/b49da8a5bc14504f73fe) by installing

```html
Install:
sudo apt-get install freetds-dev freetds-bin unixodbc-dev tdsodbc
pip install pyodbc sqlalchemy
In /etc/odbcinst.ini:

[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
```

After install I try this code and it worked, it print all records from table2

```html
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=<IP_OR_HOSTNAME>;PORT=1433;DATABASE=<DATABASE_NAME>;UID=<USERNAME>;PWD=<PASSWORD>;TDS_Version=8.0;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
for row in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Table2'):
    print (row)
```

However, I want to use SQLAlchemy with pyodbc and it does not work

```html
import urllib

from sqlalchemy import create_engine


engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=' +
    urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=<IP_OR_HOSTNAME>;PORT=1433;DATABASE=<DATABASE_NAME>;UID=<USERNAME>;PWD=<PASSWORD>;TDS_Version=8.0;')
)
for row in engine.execute('SELECT * FROM Table2'):
    print (row)
```

> ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]'schema_name' is not a recognized function name. (195) (SQLExecDirectW)")
> [SQL: SELECT schema_name()]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)

How can I connect this?

Comment: SQL Server 2000 has not been supported by Microsoft for quite a number of years now. You'll be hard pressed finding modern tools that can still connect to it (usefully). e.g.: `TDS_Version=8.0`? SQL Server 2000 only supported up to [TDS Version 7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/135d0ebe-5c4c-4a94-99bf-1811eccb9f4a)

Comment: SQLAlchemy 1.4 does not support SQL Server 2000. Try `pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.24` and see if that works for you.

Comment: @GordThompson Downgrade sqlalchemy to sqlalchemy==1.3.24 it work , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy 1.4 does not support SQL Server 2000. Use `pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.24`.